# Back button of Google Chrome after clicking a hyperlink whose target is on the same PDF document

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, pdf

PDF documents have hyperlinks to the contents on the same document (analogous to "#section" hrefs for an HTML document). Where's the back button to go back to the page I was on (where I clicked the hyperlink).

Let's say I'm on the index of a PDF tutorial, page 4, and I click on Chapter 2's hyperlink in the index that takes me to page 38. Now, if I want to go back to page 4 again, which button or shortcut should I use?

Within all browsers, except Google Chrome, you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>←</kbd> to achieve this. Is there a similar shortcut within Google Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

In that case, i would suggest to use multiple(another) Browsers or install a Google Chrome PDF extension which has short cuts.